# Python and Flask for authentication with Amazon Cognito

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, jwt, amazon-cognito

Here's the end goal: to write a Flask app that supports login/authentication using Amazon Cognito User Pools. Both frameworks are fairly new to me.

I used warrant serverless authentication to get a JWT access token from Cognito. However, I'm not sure how or what I need to verify the token as valid.
I've read through a few answers on this site as well as the following links:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decode-verify-cognito-json-token/
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrating-amazon-cognito-user-pools-with-api-gateway/

The first link suggests:

> To verify the signature of an Amazon Cognito JWT, first search for the key with a key ID that matches the key ID of the JWT. Then, use libraries to decode the token and verify the signature.

I retrieved a JWK for the public key from the provided link, but I'm not sure how to use it. What libraries could I use to decode the token, keeping in mind I am working in a Python environment? I looked at flask-jwt-extended, but the provided classes and methods don't seem to solve my exact problem. Should I override classes and functions in flask-jwt-extended to get the desired effect?

Or if I'm approaching this problem in the wrong way, any pointers or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up mostly figuring this one out, but if anyone else is curious, I used the PyJWT library decode the JWT tokens that Cognito returned. Looked pretty far into flask-jwt-extended, but the provided methods didn't cover the functionality I was looking for.

jwt.algorithms.RSAAlgorithm.from_jwk was useful for decoding the JWK to get its public key

Comment: I'm stuck at an even more basic point - how are you retrieving the JWT in your app? I tried decorating my handler with jwt_required() from flask_jwt but I get an error "flask_jwt.JWTError: Authorization Required. Request does not contain an access token" on the redirect from cognito to my landing URL. That sort of sounds like something might be misconfigured on the Cognito side but I'm noob enough on this topic that I'm not sure.